# native isnan check in C++

Tags: c++

I stumbled upon this code to check for NaN:

```
/**
 * isnan(val) returns true if val is nan.
 * We cannot rely on std::isnan or x!=x, because GCC may wrongly optimize it
 * away when compiling with -ffast-math (default in RASR).
 * This function basically does 3 things:
 *  - ignore the sign (first bit is dropped with <<1)
 *  - interpret val as an unsigned integer (union)
 *  - compares val to the nan-bitmask (ones in the exponent, non-zero significand)
 **/
template<typename T>
inline bool isnan(T val) {
    if (sizeof(val) == 4) {
        union { f32 f; u32 x; } u = { (f32)val };
        return (u.x << 1) > 0xff000000u;
    } else if (sizeof(val) == 8) {
        union { f64 f; u64 x; } u = { (f64)val };
        return (u.x << 1) > 0x7ff0000000000000u;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "isnan is not implemented for sizeof(datatype)=="
              << sizeof(val) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This looks arch dependent, right? However, I'm not sure about endianess, because no matter about little or big endian, the float and the int are probably stored in the same order.

Also, I wonder whether something like

```
volatile T x = val;
return std::isnan(x);
```

would have worked.

This was used with GCC 4.6 in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, I wonder whether something like `std::isnan((volatile)x)` would have worked.

`isnan` takes its argument by value so the `volatile` qualifier would have been discarded. In other words, no, this doesn’t work.

The code you’ve posted relies on a specific floating point representation (IEEE). It also exhibits undefined behaviour since it relies on the `union` hack to retrieve the underlying float representation.

On a note about code review, the function is badly written even if we ignore the potential problems of the previous paragraph (which are justifiable): why does the function use runtime checks rather than compile-time checks and compile time error handling? It would have been better and easier just to offer two overloads.

Comment: I changed my question to make more clear what I meant with volatile. I also wonder what the original problem might have been with std::isnan and whether volatile changes anything about that.

Comment: @Albert Your edit changes nothing about the reasoning why `std::isnan` wouldn’t work. It’s effectively the same code.

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood. So I wonder why it didn't worked, and their function worked. Also, why is volatile discarded in that case? Is that also true if it is being inlined? Unfortunately, I don't have any other refs for the comment.

Comment: @Albert Inlining is an optimisation, it doesn’t change semantics (well `-ffast-math` does, but that’s a special case). As for why `volatile` is discarded: Your `x` obviously remains `volatile` but as I said the variable is passed by value (i.e.: copied) and the *copy* of the variable is not `volatile` inside `isnan`.